# Can I submit form by clicking label?

Tags: html

I have a code that submits form by clicking `<input type="submit">`, and I want to change my form to submit when label, which is outside of the form, is clicked.
What should I do?
Here's my code:

```html
 <div class="join">
  <p>Join</p>
  <span>Join to access all features of the site!</span>
 </div>
 <form action="join/joinf" method="POST" class="joinform">
  <div class="left">
   <p>ID<span class="required"> *required</span></p> 
   <p>PW<span class="required"> *required</span></p> 
  </div>
  <div class="right">
   <p><input type="text" name="id" id="id" required>   
   <p><input type="password" name="pw" required></p>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="formsub" value="join">
 </form>

 <label for="formsub"><button>join-label</button></label>
```

Comment: Button inside a label seems rather odd. Any reason you need it this way?

Comment: why do you need/want a label outside your form to do the submit?

Comment: You can do it with  javascript's help

Answer (score 0):

Try using Jquery click element, set id for label .

```
 $('#LabelId').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#formsub").submit();
    });
```

Comment: He didn't even mention JavaScript, yet you give an answer based on a framework, at least do it in pure js.